# How to use Class function in string in another function

Tags: python, class

I need to take a string input eg 'DDDDD' and convert them into their instance eg Door() in another function

function in the Door Class

```
def get_id(self) -> str:
        return 'D'
```

subsequent function in another Class

```
def add_row(self, row: str) -> None:
    for x in row:
        x.get(id)
```

need to store it like [Door(), Door(), Door(), Door(), Door()] from the input 'DDDDD'

Comment: that is very unclear, please [edit] and add more code and explanations

Comment: is it clearer now

Comment: does your "another" class need to contain the instances of the Door class?

Comment: Adds a row of tiles to the maze. Each character in row is a Tile ID which can be used to construct the appropriate Tile instance to place in that position of the row of tiles. A precondition of this method is that the addition of a row must not violate the maze dimensions. Note: if a row string contains an empty space or an invalid or unknown Tile ID, an Empty tile should be placed in that position.

Comment: what are the other posibilities ? other than D>Door